# kill-region deletes entire buffer content instead of selected text

Tags: region, kill-ring

In emacs, i have a small text selected as shown in the picture.

[image]

When i do `eval-buffer`, i like the `kill-region` to remove only the highlighted text. But this code empties the buffer.

```
;;this is a simple comment....
(message "%s" (region-active-p))
(kill-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
```

Doesn't `region-end` retun the selection region's end?

Comment: `eval-buffer` is probably either selecting the entire buffer, but too fast to see with the naked eye; **or**, perhaps the point (region-end) is pushed to the end of the buffer so that the region envelopes everything.

Comment: From the Help for eval-buffer:

_This function preserves the position of point._

It doesn't say anything about the mark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the comments suggest, `eval-buffer` manipulates the position of point, so that by the time you call `kill-region`, `region-beginning` and `region-end` are no longer what they were when you started. The position of point is 'preserved', as @ColinBell points out, but in this case that means that point is moved during `eval-buffer`, and then restored to it's original value when it's done. So from the user's perspective, it doesn't change.

`eval-buffer` really doesn't make sense for code that is intended to modify the buffer itself. There's almost certainly a more appropriate way to do what you want.